# How to get python-poetry to detect a version of pip within a virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-poetry, isort

I'm playing around with a fork of [isort](https://github.com/PyCQA/isort.git), using [this installation guide](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/contributing/1.-contributing-guide.html) but including a `virtualenv`—though a platform install fails as well with the same error, as does an install with `curl` instead of `pip` (as detailed in the `poetry` [installation documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-the-official-installer)).

FWIW I'm on a MacBook Air with an M1 chip, which has caused countless other issues as well.

Here are the commands I've used, with some longer outputs truncated:

```bash
local-forks >> which pip
/Users/MyUser/.pyenv/shims/pip

local-forks >> pip --version
pip 22.2.1 from /Users/MyUser/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

local-forks >> git clone https://github.com/PyCQA/isort.git && cd isort
Cloning into 'isort'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 23962, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3257/3257), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (729/729), done.
remote: Total 23962 (delta 2202), reused 3120 (delta 2145), pack-reused 20705
Receiving objects: 100% (23962/23962), 22.26 MiB | 1.20 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (15197/15197), done.

local-forks/isort >> virtualenv venv && source venv/bin/activate
created virtual environment CPython3.10.7.final.0-64 in 165ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/MyUser/local-forks/isort/venv, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/MyUser/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==22.2.2, setuptools==65.3.0, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

(venv) local-forks/isort >> pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (22.2.2)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-22.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.2.2
    Uninstalling pip-22.2.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.2.2
Successfully installed pip-22.3

(venv) local-forks/isort >> pip --version
pip 22.3 from /Users/MyUser/local-forks/isort/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

(venv) local-forks/isort >> pip install poetry
...
Installing collected packages: poetry
Successfully installed poetry-1.2.2

(venv) local-forks/isort >> poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Because isort depends on pip (^21.1.1) which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
```

Given the `which` and `--version` output, it looks like everything should be set up for some `pip` auto-detector to do its job, but I'm not sure where it's even looking.